# How to decide later when a ship is captured but the dock is full?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I captured a man of war. Usually there are 3 options when the dock is full:

- Scrap ship
- Decide later
- Scrap a ship from a fleet

I want to decide later. I have cheap frigates I can scrap but they are all on missions and I can't access them till I deal with this newly captured man of war.

So I was forced to scrap the man of war, which sucked.

Why do I sometimes have the choice to decide later and other times I don't?

Comment: Have you recently unlocked all of the docks? I think the 'decide later' option is so that it gives you an option to unlock a dock using the gems? Also, certain objectives (on privateer contracts) where it explicitly states sink ships, does not seem to allow you to capture the ship.

Comment: I have unlocked all the docks. I don't think that's the problem. I could still choose when all 15 docks are full.

Comment: Does this happen every time you finish a boarding? There are certain sections in the campaign and in the privateer missions where you have to sink the ships, rather than allow them to be captured. It might be because all of your ships are out on missions, in which case you will have to capture a ship again once you have some idle ships in your fleet.